# Headphone jack doesn't work on my Asus laptop

Tags: sound, windows, laptop, 13.04

I have dual boot systems on my Asus laptop. When i run Windows 7 my headphone jack is working, but when i run Ubuntu 13.04 and reboot it to Windows 7 headphone stops produced any sound to my headphones.

I am sorry if i posted my question on wrong site. But my problem is very frustrating and i would like to resolve it with you help Ubuntuers.

If you need any further information please let me know.